# Karate Runner Path Issue

Tags: karate

When attempting to use the karate runner (version 1.3.1) with both a directory and feature files (provided in a list similar to the example given in GitHub:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJquE.png)

Karate will only pick up the feature files (not the directories), upon debugging the karate Jar, in the ResourceUtils.java:159 class I noticed that the code seems to disregard the pathRoots contents if the results variable is not empty. If this is a bug, it is still present in the codebase today, as I cross referenced with the most up-to-date version on GitHub.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pny13.png)

Apologies for censoring the values here, but I am unable to post them as they include confidential information, however, they follow the exact same structure as the first image. I have verified that the directories exist and there is no issues with the paths. I have verified that when only the directory is supplied the tests within it run without issue.

When the findResourcesByExtension() method returns it will only contain the feature files that were explicitly provided and not contain the files that are within the directory provided.

Comment: yes sounds very much like a bug. feel free to raise an issue, ideally with a way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - I would also request you to consider submitting a PR, that would be great